# Searching for a word or phrase in Windows Server 2008 R2 / Terminal Services

Tags: search, microsoft-office-2010, windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-services

We have several Terminal Services users who are migrating to Windows Server 2008 R2 and Office 2010 from Server 2003 and Office 2003. One of the questions that has come up as a result of all this is: "How do I search for a word or a phrase within documents?"

I'm having a hard time giving them a definitive answer and I've attempted the following:

1. I've tried changing the search options from 'indexed only' to
   'always search file names and contents' and that hasn't made any
   difference.
2. I've typed 'search' in the search box and that has given me the
   'Everything' tool but this appears to be restricted to the local
   volume only. I need to be able to search mapped drives.

Am I going to have to rely on a third party tool or is there something blindingly obvious that I've apparently missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go third party and have found a nifty app called [FileLocator Lite](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=filelocatorlite&page=home).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Windows Search Role first:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature FS-Search-Service
```

This will enable Windows Server 2008 R2 users to search file contents from the explorer search box. Please keep in mind that you can modify the behavior of the explorer search via the folder options menu.

Answer (score 0):

Within Windows 7 & Office 2010 - Type what you want to search for, within the search results window you can choose 'custom' - this is where you can select your network share(s). Let it search and then [File Contents] appears within the search window.

I would hazard a guess and say that TS on Windows Server 2008 R2 has the same search features as Win7.

Comment: I would agree with the same search features comment but this doesn't appear to be the case here. This issue has me frowning.

Comment: Afraid i'm not "lucky" enough to have a 2008 server here to have a look, hopefully someone else can help further :)